# How to install grub when / is encrypted (luks) and /boot is not encrypted

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, grub2, luks

I have the following partitioning:

```
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------|
   | Name | Mount point | Flag      | Size | FS    | Comment        |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------|
   | sda1 | /boot/efi   | esp, boot | 300M | FAT32 |                |
   | sda2 | /boot       |           | 2G   | EXT4  |                |
   | sda3 | /           |           |      | LUKS  | Encrypted Arch |
   | sda4 | /           |           |      | EXT4  | Clear Arch     |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------|
```

I would like to be able to choose between an encrypted Arch and a clear Arch at boot.

- Encrypted Arch's `/boot` is on sda2
- Clear Arch's `/boot` is on sda4

It is the first time I try to repair grub. I read that I should use `grub-install`, but I cannot find tutorials that would apply to my specific partitioning.

Comment: The Arch wiki should contain all you need. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Installation

Comment: As far as I understand it, in this tutorial, `/boot` and `/` are part of the same partition.

Comment: There is a very long guide to this kind of thing here. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_(GRUB) 
Unfortunately none of the examples match your objectives but you may find something that helps. I would go through this carefully and if you still cannot configure it as you want ask on the Arch forums. There are some very capable people on there but they do expect you to have done your research first